# Countdown changing to Minutes, Seconds, Hours

Tags: html, css

so i was wondering i have this Countdown that counts till Dec 23rd and it shows completely fine like Days, Hrs and so on, yet i want to as a feature have it that if you click on the Countdown it changes to only seconds till that time or only Hours, Minutes.. i searched on google but couldnt find many solutions and those who i found werent working for me

```
var countDownDate = new Date("Dec 23, 2022 08:00:00").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

  var now = new Date().getTime();

  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Website going Live in only a Couple of Minutes";
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: So how does the user indicate that they want seconds, or that they want minutes, or that they want hours?

Comment: I would have thought of it as click till you get type of thing i didnt wanna add buttons , so if you click on it it just goes in a cycle like 1 click only Hours 1 more click minutes and so on

Comment: Please could you show us what you have tried - e.g. have you put an eventListener on that element to harness the clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is maintain a count of the number of clicks (modulo 5) and show the relevant info depending on the number of clicks.

This snippet converts some of your code into a function and in update it checks how many clicks and returns the format required.

```js
const demo = document.getElementById("demo");
let numClicks = 0;

function update() {
  const now = new Date().getTime();

  const distance = countDownDate - now;

  const days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  const hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  const minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  const seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  function format() {
    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      return "Website going Live in only a Couple of Minutes";
    } else {
      switch (numClicks) {
        case 0:
          return days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
        case 1:
          return Math.floor(distance / 1000) + "s";
        case 2:
          return Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60)) + "m";
        case 3:
          return Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60)) + "h";
        case 4:
          return Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) + "d";
        default:
          alert('error - numClicks out of range. numClicks = ' + numClicks);
      }
    }
  }

  demo.innerHTML = format();
}
demo.addEventListener("click", function() {
  numClicks = (numClicks + 1) % 5;
  update();
});
const countDownDate = new Date("Dec 23, 2022 08:00:00").getTime();
const x = setInterval(function() {
  update();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Note: I've replaced var with const or let as suitable as that gives more checking on scope of variables.

Comment: Hello, thanks this works just fine :P